# What is the meaning of double colon in couchbase?

Tags: database, couchbase

I read an example of n1ql in couchbase, but don't understand the meaning of double colon in this context of query. The example is below :

```
SELECT * FROM default WHERE type = "conversation" AND ARRAY_SORT(OBJECT_NAMES(members)) = ARRAY_SORT(ARRAY_DISTINCT(["user_account::1","user_account::3","user_account::3"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Couchbase, every document/object is required to have an ID or key that is unique in that bucket. The double colon is just a common string delimiter used in Couchbase for the object's ID as part of object modeling. It is not used much or at all anywhere else in any language, code or writing. Here is [a blog post](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/key-pattern-delimiter-in-couchbase) I wrote about this exact topic a year or so ago.

Answer (score 1):

The double colons do not have any meaning. They are embedded inside a string. They are just a user convention for primary keys that have several components.